# Is it possible to setup my website so that I can ssh to my server?

Tags: linux, ssh, website

I have a server running at home that I ssh to a lot. As far as I know, I'm only able to do so over local network. Is there a way for me to set up my website so that I can ssh to my server remotely? Maybe something like

```
 $ ssh me@ssh.myweb.site
```

Answer (score 0):

SSH services use port 22. In your server, forward port 22. And on your router, also forward port 22. Then find out your public IP address at https://whatismyip.com and then you can setup a dynamic DNS for your IP address using a ddns provider. I you don't use ddns then you need to manually check your public IP address frequently and ssh using that. You can use ddclient for ddns client on your router https://sourceforge.net/p/ddclient/wiki/Home/. Then you will get a host name like `myssh.ddns.net` and try `ssh me@myssh.ddns.net`

Comment: this does not answer the OPs question.  It just states how to set up a SSH server.

Comment: @Keltari please read OP's question. He says that he does ssh to a server lot, now he wants to ssh to the server outside the LAN over internet.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your question is can you SSH to your home computer.  The answer is yes.  You can set up a SSH server on your Linux server, open a port on your router's firewall (port 22 is the default for SSH), and forward that to your server.  Harrymc has basic directions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/968641/setting-up-server-to-connect-using-ssh-over-the-internet-ubuntu-14-04), from a previous question here on Superuser.  Google something along the lines of "How to set up a SSH server at home" for more information.

However, you asked if you could do this over the web.  Technically no... and yes!  Your web server is running on port 80 (traditionally).  This means your SSH server cannot listen in on web traffic.  However, while not the method you were expecting, you can actually add SSH functionality via a web server/page.  In essence, you go to a page on your website which has a SSH terminal embedded in it.  Read this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH) for more information about this method, as well as some examples.  The advantage of these methods is that you dont need to open another port, nor do you need a device with a SSH client.